# How do I make this pandas DataFrame display data by month and also show months with 0 value?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to build a bar chart that will show how many clicks a URL has received each month.

I have a database table called Click. Every time someone clicks on the link, a new row is added to the Click table. In this table there is a column called date_clicked, which is a datetime object that is created automatically when a new row is created.

I want to take the data I have and construct a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

| Month | number of clicks |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11 | 3 |
| 2022-12 | 0 |
| 2023-01 | 4 |
| 2023-02 | 0 |
| 2023-03 | 3 |
| 2023-04 | 2 |

currently what I have as a dataframe looks like this:

- 0   2022-11-17 00:45:01
- 1   2022-11-19 02:15:26
- 2   2022-11-19 03:33:15
- 3   2022-01-03 11:14:12
- 4   2023-01-05 04:25:06
- 5   2023-01-14 09:52:36
- 6   2023-01-22 05:15:22
- 7   2023-03-15 01:34:13
  etc......

I don't really know what I'm doing with pandas but I have been trying different groupby()/reindex()/date_range() methods and using the pd.offsets.MonthEnd class and I don't feel like I'm getting any closer to the solution. I can either create a dataframe that is sorted by Month but does not include the months where there are 0 clicks. Or I can create a dataframe where it is sorted by days and DOES include the days with 0 clicks, but I can not sort it by month AND have the months with 0 clicks displayed.

Comment: Can you share an example of the input *table/dataframe* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use :

```
out = (df.assign(date_clicked = pd.to_datetime(df["date_clicked"]))
         .set_index("date_clicked").resample("M").size()
         .reset_index(name="number of clicks")
         .assign(Month= lambda x: x['date_clicked'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m"))
      )

plt.bar(out["Month"], out["number of clicks"])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel("Month")
plt.ylabel("number of clicks")
plt.yticks(range(0, out["number of clicks"].max()+1))
plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]